# Bar Chart.js with objects using custom properties - problem to show

Tags: object, chart.js, visualization

I have a set of data organized in 10 areas. In each area there are three categories: A, B and C and each of these categories has a set of data.
My goal is to achieve with html and chart.js a bar chart with a selector (it works correctly) that allows you to change AREA and then show in the chart those three CATEGORIES and their data for that AREA.

I have already read the Chart.Js documentation but I see that I can't find information for the visualization and I don't see similar cases on the internet, only this one but I follow the steps in the same way but I don't reach the result (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPsyh_KuYNA).
My problem is that it shows only the data of one of the CATEGORIES and if I change the AREA it shows me the data of another CATEGORY but not the others.

I share part of my code

```
<div class="chartBox">
                        <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
                    <select id="areax" class= "sel_area" onchange="cambioarea()">                       
                        <option value="area_1">Area 1</options>                             
                        <option value="area_2">Area 2</options>
                        <option value="area_3">Area 3</options>
                        <option value="area_4">Area 4</options>
                        <option value="area_5">Area 5</options>
                        <option value="area_6">Area 6</options>
                        <option value="area_7">Area 7</options>
                        <option value="area_8">Area 8</options>
                        <option value="area_9">Area 9</options>
                        <option value="area_10">Area 10</options>
                    </select>
                    </div>
// setup 
const data = {
        //labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],    
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Kms. por area',
            //data: [50, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],
            data: [
            {id: 'A', calzada:
                {
                    area_1: {a:613.810},
                    area_2: {a:600.586},
                    area_3: {a:1091.87}, 
                    area_4: {a:656.29},
                    area_5: {a:866.47},
                    area_6: {a:2262.059},
                    area_7: {a:1055.978},
                    area_8: {a:490.487}, 
                    area_9: {a:763.41},
                    area_10: {a:1099.84},
                }
            },
            {id: 'B', calzada:
                {
                    area_1: {b:11.981},
                    area_2: {b:209.617},
                    area_3: {b:317.616},
                    area_4: {b:106.509},
                    area_5: {b:70.190},
                    area_6: {b:84.109},
                    area_7: {b:18.875},
                    area_8: {b:39.619},
                    area_9: {b:27.899},
                    area_10: {b:50.787},
                }
            },
            {id: 'C', calzada:
                {
                    area_1: {c:534.647},
                    area_2: {c:988.239},
                    area_3: {c:519.770},
                    area_4: {c:672.867},
                    area_5: {c:725.431},
                    area_6: {c:1080.430},
                    area_7: {c:916.132},
                    area_8: {c:1224.730},
                    area_9: {c:1193.990},
                    area_10: {c:211.585},
                }
            }],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ff0127',
                '#ffffff',
                '#db6adb'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'black',
                'black',
                'black',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    };

    // config 
    const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data,             // tambien funciona como:  data:data,
        options: {
            parsing: {
                xAxisKey: 'id',
                yAxisKey: 'calzada.area_1.a'
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    };
          
    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
        );
function cambioarea(){
        const areax = document.getElementById('areax').value;
        console.log(areax);
        myChart.config.options.parsing.yAxisKey = `calzada.${areax}.a`;
        myChart.config.options.parsing.yAxisKey = `calzada.${areax}.b`;
        myChart.config.options.parsing.yAxisKey = `calzada.${areax}.c`;
        myChart.update();
    }
```

This is what happens :
[image]

I think my problem is in my function CAMBIOAREA.
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot better to let ChartJS handle the show/hide of some data.

For example, if you place each area in a dataset, you can use the labels at the top to toggle them.

See this example:

```js
const backgroundColor = ["red", "blue", "green"];
const data = {  
    labels: [ 'a','b','c'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "area 1",
        data: [65, 59, 80],
        backgroundColor
      },
      {
        label: "area 2",
        data: [50, 21, 12],
        hidden: true,
        backgroundColor
      }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data,       
    
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
};



// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chartBox">
    <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

---

Otherwise, you could hide those labels to toggle, and then hide/show the sets when the  changes:

```js
//Hide
chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden=true;
chart.update();

//Show
chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden=false;
chart.update();
```

Comment: Fantastic! Is possible to set colors for each bar? But well this is another approach because I want to use the dropbox select instead of delete each AREA inside de chart.

Comment: I've added some colors to the bars. Would this solution be valid if the dropbox toggles the datasets?

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to achieve is to use Dropbox.
This way it will be possible to see only the AREA you want by selecting it with the dropbox select and avoid the need to delete the other AREAS. So for that purpose I tried `cambioarea()` function and `<select>`  but without success because it only works with one CATEGORY.

Comment: I think @0stone0 that to achieve that all three categories (a, b, c) can appear at the same time for only one AREA and change the AREA with a <select> dropbox in my dataset to each show its own categories, it is neccesary to change the way the `cambioarea` function is called at the end of my script. If anyone has another approach or idea, it's welcome.